# integral of $x - x_0$

Tags: integration

How to evaluate:
$$\int (x-x_0)dx$$
One way is direct:
$$\int x dx - \int x_0 dx = \frac{x^2}{2} - x x_0 +C$$
The other way is assuming $x - x_0 = \tau$, $dx=d\tau$, we get
$$\int \tau d\tau = \frac{\tau^2}{2} = \frac{(x - x_0)^2}{2} + C$$
Which one is the right one? If both are correct when to choose one over the other?

Thanks,

Bhupala

Comment: They are the same. No need to prefer one over the other. If you expand $(x-x_0)^{2}$ in the second answer you get the first one (with a different constant).

Comment: As Kavi pointed out, both are fine.In this example the first option seems rather straightforward .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct and equivalent.

$$\int x dx - \int x_0 dx = \frac{x^2}{2} - x x_0 +C_1$$
$$\int \tau d\tau = \frac{\tau^2}{2} = \frac{(x - x_0)^2}{2} + C_2=\frac{x^2}{2} - x x_0+\frac{x_0^2}{2}+C_2$$

Now you can see that $\frac{x_0^2}{2} + C_2$ is just another constant and can be thought of the same as $C_1$, i.e. $C_1=\frac{x_0^2}{2} + C_2$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2} + C=\frac{x^2+x_0^2-2xx_0}{2} + C=\frac{x^2+x_0^2}{2}- xx_0 + C=\frac{x^2}{2}- xx_0 + C'
$$
for some constant $C'$.